# How to zero pad numbers in file names in Bash?

Tags: bash, rename

What is the best way, using Bash, to rename files in the form:

```
(foo1, foo2, ..., foo1300, ..., fooN)
```

With zero-padded file names:

```
(foo00001, foo00002, ..., foo01300, ..., fooN)
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In case `N` is not a priori fixed:

```
for f in foo[0-9]*; do
  mv "$f" "$(printf 'foo%05d' "${f#foo}")"
done
```

Comment: spent a solid hour looking an applicable solution this morning, and this by far the "best" one I came across, ie. working on Linux, macOS, and no dependency on the `rename` utility.

On side note, this solution did strip the "file extensions"  for the files I was working with, so after applying this solution, a

`for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.ext"; done`

was a quick band-aid® to get the desired extension back onto the files I was working with. 

Comment: This hiccups on files named 050 (for example: a number beginning with a zero is interpreted as octal base), outputting 00040 (not the expected 00050).  See my answer, below.

Comment: This stops with a question if your files are just foo1 and foo01.

Answer (score 81):

It's not pure bash, but much easier with the Perl version of `rename`:

```
rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%05d",$&)/e' foo*
```

Where `'s/\d+/sprintf("%05d",$&)/e'` is the Perl replace regular expression.

- `\d+` will match the first set of numbers (at least one number)
- `sprintf("%05d",$&)` will pass the matched numbers to Perl's `sprintf`, and `%05d` will pad to five digits

Comment: It handles filenames with spaces too.

Comment: Note: rename != rename https://stackoverflow.com/a/31408886/318765

Answer (score 23):

I had a more complex case where the file names had a postfix as well as a prefix. I also needed to perform a subtraction on the number from the filename.

For example, I wanted `foo56.png` to become `foo00000055.png`.

I hope this helps if you're doing something more complex.

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix="foo"
postfix=".png"
targetDir="../newframes"
paddingLength=8

for file in ${prefix}[0-9]*${postfix}; do
  # strip the prefix off the file name
  postfile=${file#$prefix}
  # strip the postfix off the file name
  number=${postfile%$postfix}
  # subtract 1 from the resulting number
  i=$((number-1))
  # copy to a new name with padded zeros in a new folder
  cp ${file} "$targetDir"/$(printf $prefix%0${paddingLength}d$postfix $i)
done
```

Answer (score 9):

Pure Bash, no external processes other than 'mv':

```
for file in foo*; do
  newnumber='00000'${file#foo}      # get number, pack with zeros
  newnumber=${newnumber:(-5)}       # the last five characters
  mv $file foo$newnumber            # rename
done
```

Answer (score 8):

To left-pad numbers in filenames (here numeric file names with alphabetic extensions, e.g. 1.abc):

```bash
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 0 Mar 28 17:24 010
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 0 Mar 28 18:09 050
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 0 Mar 28 17:23 050.zzz
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 0 Mar 28 17:24 10
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 0 Mar 28 17:23 1.zzz

$ for f in [0-9]*.[a-z]*; do tmp=`echo $f | awk -F. '{printf "%04d.%s\n", $1, $2}'`; mv "$f" "$tmp"; done;

$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 0 Mar 28 17:23 0001.zzz
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 0 Mar 28 17:23 0050.zzz
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 0 Mar 28 17:24 010
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 0 Mar 28 18:09 050
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 0 Mar 28 17:24 10
```

**Explanation**

```bash
for f in [0-9]*.[a-z]*; do tmp=`echo $f | \
awk -F. '{printf "%04d.%s\n", $1, $2}'`; mv "$f" "$tmp"; done;
```

- note the backticks: `` `echo ... $2}\` ``  (The backslash, \, immediately above just splits that one-liner over two lines for readability)
- in a loop find files that are named as numbers with lowercase alphabet extensions: `[0-9]*.[a-z]*`
- echo that filename (`$f`) to pass it to `awk`
- `-F.` : `awk` field separator, a period (`.`): if matched, separates the file names as two fields (`$1` = number; `$2` = extension)
- format with `printf`: print first field (`$1`, the number part) as 4 digits (`%04d`), then print the period, then print the second field (`$2`: the extension) as a string (`%s`).  All of that is assigned to the `$tmp` variable
- lastly, move the source file (`$f`) to the new filename (`$tmp`)

Comment: Thanks Victoria, this is the answer that helped me the most! Great explanation!

Answer (score 7):

The oneline command that I use is this:

```
ls * | cat -n | while read i f; do mv "$f" `printf "PATTERN" "$i"`; done
```

PATTERN can be for example:

- rename with increment counter: `%04d.${f#*.}` (keep original file extension)
- rename with increment counter with prefix: `photo_%04d.${f#*.}` (keep original extension)
- rename with increment counter and change extension to jpg: `%04d.jpg`
- rename with increment counter with prefix and file basename: `photo_$(basename $f .${f#*.})_%04d.${f#*.}`
- ...

You can filter the file to rename with for example `ls *.jpg | ...`

You have available the variable `f` that is the file name and `i` that is the counter.

For your question the right command is:

```
ls * | cat -n | while read i f; do mv "$f" `printf "foo%d05" "$i"`; done
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will do it:

```
for ((i=1; i<=N; i++)) ; do mv foo$i `printf foo%05d $i` ; done
```

**EDIT:** changed to use ((i=1,...)), thanks [mweerden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4285/mweerden)!

Comment: Instead of using seq I would suggest writing for ((i=1; i<=N; i++)); do etc. Besides being part of bash, this also avoids having to first generate all numbers and then executing the for.

Comment: You don't need to use a subshell to invoke printf.  `print -v var` will store the result in `var` variable.

Answer (score 1):

My solution replaces numbers, **everywhere in a string**

```sh
for f in * ; do
    number=`echo $f | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'`
    padded=`printf "%04d" $number`
    echo $f | sed "s/${number}/${padded}/";
done
```

You can easily try it, since it just prints transformed file names (no filesystem operations are performed).

### Explanation:

#### Looping through list of files

A loop: `for f in * ; do ;done`, lists all files and passes each filename as `$f` variable to loop body.

#### Grabbing the number from string

With `echo $f | sed` we pipe variable `$f` to `sed` program.

In command `sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'`, part `[^0-9]*` with modifier `^` tells to match opposite from digit 0-9 (not a number) and then remove it it with empty replacement `//`. Why not just remove `[a-z]`? Because filename can contain dots, dashes etc. So, we strip everything, that is not a number and get a number.

Next, we assign the result to `number` variable. Remember to not put spaces in assignment, like `number = …`, because you get different behavior.

We assign execution result of a command to variable, wrapping the command with backtick symbols `.

#### Zero padding

Command `printf "%04d" $number` changes format of a number to 4 digits and adds zeros if our number contains less than 4 digits.

#### Replacing number to zero-padded number

We use `sed` again with replacement command like `s/substring/replacement/`. To interpret our variables, we use double quotes and substitute our variables in this way `${number}`.

---

The script above just prints transformed names, so, let's do actual renaming job:

```
for f in *.js ; do
    number=`echo $f | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'`
    padded=`printf "%04d" $number`
    new_name=`echo $f | sed "s/${number}/${padded}/"`
    mv $f $new_name;
done
```

Hope this helps someone.

I spent several hours to figure this out.

Comment: This may stop with an overwrite question even with only two files, e.g., file1.js and file01.js.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is derived from Chris Conway's accepted answer but **assumes your files have an extension** (unlike Chris' answer). Just paste this (rather long) one liner into your command line.

```
for f in foo[0-9]*; do mv "$f" "$(printf 'foo%05d' "${f#foo}" 2> /dev/null)"; done; for f in foo[0-9]*; do mv "$f" "$f.ext"; done;
```

**OPTIONAL ADDITIONAL INFO**

This script will rename

```
foo1.ext    > foo00001.ext
foo2.ext    > foo00002.ext
foo1300.ext > foo01300.ext
```

To test it on your machine, just paste this one liner into an **EMPTY** directory.

```
rm * 2> /dev/null; touch foo1.ext foo2.ext foo1300.ext; for f in foo[0-9]*; do mv "$f" "$(printf 'foo%05d' "${f#foo}" 2> /dev/null)"; done; for f in foo[0-9]*; do mv "$f" "$f.ext"; done;
```

This deletes the content of the directory, creates the files in the above example and then does the batch rename.

For those who don't need a one liner, the script indented looks like this.

```
for f in foo[0-9]*;
  do mv "$f" "$(printf 'foo%05d' "${f#foo}" 2> /dev/null)";
done;

for f in foo[0-9]*;
  do mv "$f" "$f.ext";
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution that assumes a fixed length prefix (your "foo") and fixed length padding.  If you need more flexibility, maybe this will at least be a helpful starting point.

```
#!/bin/bash

# some test data
files="foo1
foo2
foo100
foo200
foo9999"

for f in $files; do
    prefix=`echo "$f" | cut -c 1-3`        # chars 1-3 = "foo"
    number=`echo "$f" | cut -c 4-`         # chars 4-end = the number
    printf "%s%04d\n" "$prefix" "$number"
done
```