# Adding numbered prefixes to many files in folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, batch-file, command

I would like to add a numbered prefixes to all my folders in a folder.

For example, I have the following

1. Picture_a.jpg
2. Picture_b.jpg
3. Picture_c.jpg

I want to have

1. 01_Picture_a.jpg
2. 02_Picture_b.jpg
3. 03_Picture_c.jpg

I have 91 photos that I want to rename in this fashion. Thanks!

Comment: `for` loop and `printf`...

Comment: hi, can you teach me how to do it ? I know about "for f in `ls *.jpg` ; do mv "$f" "01_$f" ; done, but how can i set 01 to increase by a value of 1 until 91? Also, it has to be 01 and not 1. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672301/linux-shell-script-to-add-leading-zeros-to-file-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `for` loop to iterate over the files and `printf` to make the new filename should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
for orig in *.jpg
do
    new=$(printf "%02d_%s" $i $orig)
    mv $orig $new
    ((i++))
done
```