# Rename large number of files in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a large list of files that I want to rename.

Much like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672301/linux-shell-script-to-add-leading-zeros-to-file-names)

So this is what my files look like

```
something.pcap1
something.pcap10
something.pcap11
something.pcap12
...
something.pcap111
something.pcap1111
```

essentially I want to rename all of the files so that the numbers get padded with 0's and they are 5 digit numbers.

```
something.pcap00001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple for loop should do the trick (can be script file):

```
for file in $(ls -1 something.pcap*); do
    [[ ${file} =~ ^something.pcap([[:digit:]]*).* ]]
    newfile=$(printf "something.pcap%05d" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]})
    mv ${file} ${newfile}
done
```

Comment: That is a good one :). +1. Never seen BASH_REMATCH usage before

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
rename 's/\d+$/sprintf("%05d",$&)/e' soemthing.pcap*
```

Note: this works with the **rename** as found in debian and its derivates.

Comment: what about centos. It attempted it and it did not work. And by did not work, I mean the file names remained the same.

Comment: Good question.  In deb rename is a symlink to /usr/bin/prename, which seems to be part of deb's perl installation.  Maybe check whether Centos' perl has a script executable with rename in the name?  If you can't - the script is tiny; here's a URL to the paste http://pastebin.com/7QkWtPSd

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls something.pcap*); do
 q=$(echo $i|sed -e 's/pcap/pcap00000/;s/pcap0*\([0-9]\{6,\}\)$/pcap\1/')
 mv $i $q
done
```

I hope this will help