# Recursively counting files in a Linux directory

Tags: linux, bash

How can I recursively count files in a Linux directory?

I found this:

```
find DIR_NAME -type f ¦ wc -l
```

But when I run this it returns the following error.

> find: paths must precede expression: ¦

Comment: You are confusing the broken bar `¦` (ASCII 166) with the vertical bar `|` (ASCII 124) used for [UNIX pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29).

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou Isn't it called a pipe?

Comment: @DaveStephens Yes, it's also called that. It's also called a Sheffer stroke, verti-bar, vbar, stick, vertical line, vertical slash, bar, obelisk, glidus.

Comment: In RFC20 it's called "vertical line". "Pipe" is the name of the shell operator, rather than the name of the symbol. Just as `*` is the "asterisk" ASCII character, but "times" in some other contexts.

Comment: @slim That is by far the most useful answer. By far, and then some.

Answer (score 1863, accepted):

This should work:

```
find DIR_NAME -type f | wc -l
```

**Explanation:**

- `-type f` to include only files.
- `|` (**and not `¦`**) redirects `find` command's standard output to `wc` command's standard input.
- `wc` (short for word count) counts newlines, words and bytes on its input ([docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html)).
- `-l` to count just newlines.

**Notes:**

- Replace `DIR_NAME` with `.` to execute the command in the current folder.
- You can also remove the `-type f` to include directories (and symlinks) in the count.
- It's possible this command will overcount if filenames can contain newline characters.

**Explanation of why your example does not work:**

In the command you showed, you do not use the "Pipe" (`|`) to kind-of connect two commands, but the broken bar (`¦`) which the shell does not recognize as a command or something similar. That's why you get that error message.

Comment: Remove the `-type f` to include directories in the count

Comment: Is there a faster method? Because it really takes some time if you apply it to /

Comment: Aoeu the problem is not the find command it is the amount of files you are asking it to handle. I just ran the command in a directory containing 95,000 files in 30 subdirectories. It took only a few seconds on my laptop.

Comment: If there is any possibility that file names contain the newline character you might want to use the `-print0` flag.

Comment: @gaboroncancio That's not going to help, unless some implementation of `wc` has an option to read a null terminated list. See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: If your files have newlines in them, you can still use find to do it by using an -exec instead of a print:  `find . -type f -exec echo \; | wc -l`.  In this way, you are not actually outputting the filenames, but you are outputting a single blank line per file encountered, regardless of the name, so the line count will work in any case.  print0 can also work if you just count null characters:  `find . -type f -print0 | tr -dc '\0' | wc -c`.  In this case, tr deletes all non-null characters and wc counts the characters fed into it.

Comment: It's slow because it really does have to traverse the whole filesystem. It opens and reads every directory it finds. There is no faster way; filesystems don't store this stuff anywhere more accessible. It'll be faster after caching, or on a faster storage medium.

Comment: **Note**: You can add `-name "*.ext"` to `find` to count the number of files of a specific extension type.

Comment: @paulsm4 do you know how to get the directories as well?

Comment: This solution does not take filename that contain newlines into account.

Comment: Look at [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50009079/6862601)'s solution which robustly handles file names that might have newlines in them.

Comment: `DIR_NAME` can be omitted if you want to count the files recursively from the current directory.

Comment: How to do this just for the current directory and not recursive (for all sub directories)? `ls | wc -l`

Comment: To me, this is good, but not the best, good for dozens of files, for millions better use `ncdu`

Comment: This gives the number of lines in the list of files, not the contents. I tried --files0-from=- option but that ignored line breaks in the input and rejected the amalgamation with "file name too long".

Comment: ```ls -R -1 /root/mydir/ | wc -l```

Answer (score 141):

For the current directory:

```
find -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: This solution does not take filename that contain newlines into account.

Comment: For the current directory, you don't even need the `.`

Comment: Actually, on some platforms, you *do* need to spell out `find .`

Comment: @Kusalanandra Your comment applies to almost every answer here.

Answer (score 110):

If you want a breakdown of how many files are in each dir under your current dir:

```
for i in */ .*/ ; do 
    echo -n $i": " ; 
    (find "$i" -type f | wc -l) ; 
done
```

That can go all on one line, of course.  The parenthesis clarify whose output `wc -l` is supposed to be watching (`find $i -type f` in this case).

Comment: It could get stuck on directories with spaces in their names. Changing the first line to `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do` fixes it. See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Using `find` for the outer loop is just a needless complication. `for i in */`; do`

Comment: function countit {
  for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d) ; do 
    file_count=$(find $i -type f | wc -l) ; 
    echo "$file_count: $i" ; 
  done
};


countit | sort -n -r

Comment: Finally this is what I needed. My folders have thousands of files so printing them with tree or anything else is not an option

Comment: This includes ../ and doesn't seem to go forward — meaning it's not regressive.

Answer (score 104):

On my computer, `rsync` is a little bit faster than `find | wc -l` in the accepted answer:

```
$ rsync --stats --dry-run -ax /path/to/dir /tmp

Number of files: 173076
Number of files transferred: 150481
Total file size: 8414946241 bytes
Total transferred file size: 8414932602 bytes
```

The second line has the number of files, 150,481 in the above example. As a bonus you get the total size as well (in bytes).

Remarks:

- the first line is a count of files, directories, symlinks, etc all together, that's why it is bigger than the second line.
- the `--dry-run` (or `-n` for short) option is important to not actually transfer the files!
- I used the `-x` option to "don't cross filesystem boundaries", which means if you execute it for `/` and you have external hard disks attached, it will only count the files on the root partition.

Comment: I like your idea of using rsync here. I'd never have thought about it!

Comment: Thanks @Qeole, the idea is not mine though. I read it several years ago somewhere that rsync is the fastest to delete a folder with lots of files and subfolders, so I thought it might be quickly to count files as well.

Comment: Tried this. After running both twice beforehand to populate the fs cache, `find ~ -type f | wc -l` took 1.7/0.5/1.33 seconds (real/user/sys). `rsync --stats --dry-run -ax ~ /xxx` took 4.4/3.1/2.1 seconds. That's for about 500,000 files on SSD.

Comment: Dunno what version of rsync you used, but in 3.1.2 it's a little easier to read: `Number of files: 487 (reg: 295, dir: 192)`

Comment: I used the default rsync on macOS: `rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29`

Comment: You could also include -h to get file size in human readable form i.e.: MB, GB etc

Answer (score 67):

You can use

```
$ tree
```

after installing the **tree** package with

```
$ sudo apt-get install tree
```

(on a Debian / Mint / Ubuntu Linux machine).

The command shows not only the count of the files, but also the count of the directories, separately. The option -L can be used to specify the maximum display level (which, by default, is the maximum depth of the directory tree).

Hidden files can be included too by supplying the `-a` option .

Comment: This is actually the simplest way to see number of directories and files.

Comment: From the man page: _By default tree does not print hidden files_. You have to supply the `-a` option to include them.

Comment: To install this on macOS, use `brew` and run `brew install tree`, preferable after running `brew update`.

Comment: It's also printing all the filenames, so it will be slow if you have many files.

Comment: Wow, very nice tool, it can print folders colorized, list only folders, output as JSON. It can list 34k folders and 51k files in very few seconds. Olé!

Comment: On my system, this doesn't display file count. Is there a flag for that?

Comment: This is a _very_ bad idea if you have lots of files

Answer (score 56):

Since filenames in UNIX may contain newlines (yes, newlines), `wc -l` might count too many files. I would print a dot for every file and then count the dots:

```
find DIR_NAME -type f -printf "." | wc -c
```

Note: The `-printf` option does only work with find from GNU findutils. You may need to install it, on a Mac for example.

Comment: Looks like this is the only solution that handles files with newlines in their names.  Upvoted.

Comment: hihi :) I love newlines in filenames. That makes them just more readable.

Comment: I mean, newlines in the file *names* not the content!

Comment: I was just joking... Yeah, newlines in filenames always have to be taken into account. They could come from malicious content or less spectacular, from a typo.

Comment: This will not work for every `find`. On OSX, you need to install GNU Find, for example, `brew install findutils`.

Comment: @TA_intern That's right. Didn't know this.

Comment: a more POSIX friendly version is probably using `-print0` and counting the null bytes in the output, or running some kind of `-exec echo`

Answer (score 24):

Combining several of the answers here together, the most useful solution seems to be:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'echo -e $(find "{}" -printf "\n" | wc -l) "{}"' |
sort -n
```

It can handle odd things like file names that include spaces parenthesis and even new lines. It also sorts the output by the number of files.

You can increase the number after `-maxdepth` to get sub directories counted too. Keep in mind that this can potentially take a long time, particularly if you have a highly nested directory structure in combination with a high `-maxdepth` number.

Comment: What's with the `echo -e`? I guess you put it in to fold any newlines, but it will also mangle any other irregular whitespace, and attempt to expand any wildcard characters present verbatim in the file names. I'd go simply with something like `find .* * -type d -execdir sh -c 'find . -type f -printf "\n" | wc -l; pwd'` and live with any aberrations in the output, or maybe play with Bash's `printf "%q"` for printing the directory name.

Comment: this is the best answer for doing more than one dir at a time and capturing dirs with white space!

Answer (score 18):

If you want to know how many files and sub-directories exist from the present working directory you can use this one-liner

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'echo -e $(find {} | wc -l) {}' | sort -n
```

This will work in GNU flavour, and just omit the -e from the echo command for BSD linux (e.g. OSX).

Comment: Excellent solution! The only issue I found was directories with spaces or special characters. Add quotes where the dir name is used: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'echo -e $(find "{}" | wc -l) "{}"' | sort -n`

Comment: I've modified it a bit and it works quite well for me: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'echo $(find {} | wc -l) \\t {}' | sort -rn | less`

Comment: My comments on @Sebastian's answer apply here too. The use of `echo -e` (or just ` echo` as in the preceding comment) on an unquoted directory name trades one problem for another.

Answer (score 17):

If what you need is to count a **specific file type** *recursively*, you can do:

```sh
find YOUR_PATH -name '*.html' -type f | wc -l
```

`-l` is just to display the number of lines in the output.

If you need to exclude certain folders, use `-not -path`

```sh
find . -not -path './node_modules/*' -name '*.js' -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: The extension is part of the filename and may not represent the file TYPE

Answer (score 16):

You can use the command [`ncdu`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncdu). It will recursively count how many files a Linux directory contains. Here is an example of output:

[image]

It has a progress bar, which is convenient if you have many files:

[image]

To install  it on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ncdu
```

---

Benchmark: I used https://archive.org/details/cv_corpus_v1.tar (380390 files, 11 GB) as the folder where one has to count the number of files.

- `find . -type f | wc -l`: around 1m20s to complete
- `ncdu`: around 1m20s to complete

Comment: That mainly calculates the disk usage, not the number of files. This additional overhead is likely not wanted. (besides the need to install an additional package for something that can be done with standard POSIX utilities)

Comment: @[hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) It does compute the  the number of files, as shown in red in the first screenshot. It took me a few minutes for ~2 million files, so the speed is not too bad.

Comment: have you compared it to `find FOLDER -type f -printf "." | wc -c`?

Comment: @hek2mgl I added a reproducible benchmark in the answer, I ran it twice and I didn't see any difference between `find . -type f | wc -l` and `ncdu`.

Comment: yes, looks like `find` is under the hood executing more or less the same system calls as `du` which is the backend for `ncdu`. Just straced them.

Comment: Looks like I was a bit too fast to give greenlight here. I just tried that in my src folder (171200 files) `find` took 0.17 sec. `du -sh` took 18 sec which is more than 100 times slower! I just used a bad example for my strace. Actually that's what I expected

Comment: @hek2mgl did you try with ncdu?

Comment: @hek2mgl So what's the runtime?

Comment: @hek2mgl well I guess it's slower in some cases then.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt loved it. I've ton of files in a folder and having a progress bar is life saver. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Here 3 miliions of files was captured in 10 seconds by `ncdu`. Indefinitely in others "word count" options.

Comment: Just adding my usage results here:
There were `490,172` directories and total of `12,569,171` files.
Max depth was `2`. Total disk usage `~300GB`
`ncdu` took `~45 min` to produce the results and total items count includes files+directories
`find . -type f | wc -l` took `~10 min` to output file count

Comment: Press `c` inside `ncdu` to enable a display of recursive file counts next to the file/folder size. Discovered this today by pressing `?` (as it says on the top)

Answer (score 13):

```
tree $DIR_PATH | tail -1
```

Sample Output:

> 5309 directories, 2122 files

Comment: This is the simplest solution that produces (almost) the precise information requested. The only thing closer for this solution would be to pipe it through `cut -d',' -f2`.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to avoid error cases, don't allow `wc -l` to see files with newlines (which it will count as 2+ files)

e.g. Consider a case where we have a single file with a single EOL character in it

```
> mkdir emptydir && cd emptydir
> touch $'file with EOL(\n) character in it'
> find -type f
./file with EOL(?) character in it
> find -type f | wc -l
2
```

Since at least gnu `wc` does not appear to have an option to read/count a null terminated list (except from a file), the easiest solution would just be to not pass it filenames, but a static output each time a file is found, e.g. in the same directory as above

```
> find -type f -exec printf '\n' \; | wc -l
1
```

Or if your `find` supports it

```
> find -type f -printf '\n' | wc -l
1
```

Answer (score 5):

To determine how many files there are in the current directory, put in `ls -1 | wc -l`. This uses `wc` to do a count of the number of lines `(-l)` in the output of `ls -1`. It doesn't count dotfiles. Please note that `ls -l` (that's an "L" rather than a "1" as in the previous examples) which I used in previous versions of this HOWTO will actually give you a file count one greater than the actual count. Thanks to Kam Nejad for this point.

If you want to count only files and NOT include symbolic links (just an example of what else you could do), you could use `ls -l | grep -v ^l | wc -l` (that's an "L" not a "1" this time, we want a "long" listing here). `grep` checks for any line beginning with "l" (indicating a link), and discards that line (-v).

Relative speed: "ls -1 /usr/bin/ | wc -l" takes about 1.03 seconds on an unloaded 486SX25 (/usr/bin/ on this machine has 355 files). "`ls -l /usr/bin/ | grep -v ^l | wc -l`" takes about 1.19 seconds.

Source: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x700.html

Comment: `ls -l` must do `stat` syscall on every file to read its size, mtime and other properties, which is slow. On big directories (100.000+ files) running `ls -l` can take several minutes. So to only count files, always use `ls -1 | wc -l`.

Comment: A 486SX25, nice

Comment: `ls -1` can still be slow in large directories, because it has to sort the files. Simply `printf '%s\n' *` does the same thing, and avoids the external `ls` call (which is [problematic](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) anyhow) but the most efficient soluton is to use a command which doesn't perform any sorting, such as `find`. (The glob output is sorted by the shell.)

Comment: When I do this with only one file in a folder the answer is 2.

Answer (score 4):

With bash:

Create an array of entries with ( ) and get the count with #.

```
FILES=(./*); echo ${#FILES[@]}
```

Ok that doesn't recursively count files but I wanted to show the simple option first. A common use case might be for creating rollover backups of a file. This will create logfile.1, logfile.2, logfile.3 etc.

```
CNT=(./logfile*); mv logfile logfile.${#CNT[@]}
```

Recursive count with bash 4+ `globstar` enabled (as mentioned by @tripleee)

```
FILES=(**/*); echo ${#FILES[@]}
```

To get the count of files recursively we can still use find in the same way.

```
FILES=(`find . -type f`); echo ${#FILES[@]}
```

Comment: Modern shells support `**/*` for recursive enumeration. It's still less efficient than `find` on large directories because the shell has to sort the files in each directory.

Comment: Storing the whole search in an Bash array just to count it later is rather inefficient and can eat up a lot of memory until the enumeration completes. For very large directory trees this can be a real problem.

Answer (score 4):

For directories with spaces in the name ... (based on various answers above) -- recursively print directory name with number of files within:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do echo -n $i": " ; ls -p "$i" | grep -v / | wc -l ; done
```

---

**Example** (formatted for readability):

```
pwd
  /mnt/Vancouver/Programming/scripts/claws/corpus

ls -l
  total 8
  drwxr-xr-x 2 victoria victoria 4096 Mar 28 15:02 'Catabolism - Autophagy; Phagosomes; Mitophagy'
  drwxr-xr-x 3 victoria victoria 4096 Mar 29 16:04 'Catabolism - Lysosomes'

ls 'Catabolism - Autophagy; Phagosomes; Mitophagy'/ | wc -l
  138

## 2 dir (one with 28 files; other with 1 file):
ls 'Catabolism - Lysosomes'/ | wc -l
  29
```

The directory structure is better visualized using `tree`:

```
tree -L 3 -F .
  .
  ├── Catabolism - Autophagy; Phagosomes; Mitophagy/
  │   ├── 1
  │   ├── 10
  │   ├── [ ... SNIP! (138 files, total) ... ]
  │   ├── 98
  │   └── 99
  └── Catabolism - Lysosomes/
      ├── 1
      ├── 10
      ├── [ ... SNIP! (28 files, total) ... ]
      ├── 8
      ├── 9
      └── aaa/
          └── bbb

  3 directories, 167 files

man find | grep mindep
  -mindepth levels
    Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than levels
    (a non-negative integer).  -mindepth 1 means process all files
    except the starting-points.
```

`ls -p | grep -v /` (used below) is from answer 2 at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48492/list-only-regular-files-but-not-directories-in-current-directory

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do echo -n $i": " ; ls -p "$i" | grep -v / | wc -l ; done
./Catabolism - Autophagy; Phagosomes; Mitophagy: 138
./Catabolism - Lysosomes: 28
./Catabolism - Lysosomes/aaa: 1
```

---

**Applcation:**  I want to find the max number of files among several hundred directories (all depth = 1) [output below again formatted for readability]:

```
date; pwd
    Fri Mar 29 20:08:08 PDT 2019
    /home/victoria/Mail/2_RESEARCH - NEWS

time find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do echo -n $i": " ; ls -p "$i" | grep -v / | wc -l ; done > ../../aaa
    0:00.03

[victoria@victoria 2_RESEARCH - NEWS]$ head -n5 ../../aaa
    ./RNA - Exosomes: 26
    ./Cellular Signaling - Receptors: 213
    ./Catabolism - Autophagy; Phagosomes; Mitophagy: 138
    ./Stress - Physiological, Cellular - General: 261
    ./Ancient DNA; Ancient Protein: 34

[victoria@victoria 2_RESEARCH - NEWS]$ sed -r 's/(^.*): ([0-9]{1,8}$)/\2: \1/g' ../../aaa | sort -V | (head; echo ''; tail)

    0: ./Genomics - Gene Drive
    1: ./Causality; Causal Relationships
    1: ./Cloning
    1: ./GenMAPP 2
    1: ./Pathway Interaction Database
    1: ./Wasps
    2: ./Cellular Signaling - Ras-MAPK Pathway
    2: ./Cell Death - Ferroptosis
    2: ./Diet - Apples
    2: ./Environment - Waste Management

    988: ./Genomics - PPM (Personalized & Precision Medicine)
    1113: ./Microbes - Pathogens, Parasites
    1418: ./Health - Female
    1420: ./Immunity, Inflammation - General
    1522: ./Science, Research - Miscellaneous
    1797: ./Genomics
    1910: ./Neuroscience, Neurobiology
    2740: ./Genomics - Functional
    3943: ./Cancer
    4375: ./Health - Disease
```

`sort -V` is a natural sort.  ... So, my max number of files in any of those (Claws Mail) directories is 4375 files.  If I left-pad (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55409116/1904943) those filenames -- they are all named numerically, starting with 1, in each directory -- and pad to 5 total digits, I should be ok.

---

**Addendum**

Find the total number of files, subdirectories in a directory.

```
$ date; pwd
Tue 14 May 2019 04:08:31 PM PDT
/home/victoria/Mail/2_RESEARCH - NEWS

$ ls | head; echo; ls | tail
Acoustics
Ageing
Ageing - Calorie (Dietary) Restriction
Ageing - Senescence
Agriculture, Aquaculture, Fisheries
Ancient DNA; Ancient Protein
Anthropology, Archaeology
Ants
Archaeology
ARO-Relevant Literature, News

Transcriptome - CAGE
Transcriptome - FISSEQ
Transcriptome - RNA-seq
Translational Science, Medicine
Transposons
USACEHR-Relevant Literature
Vaccines
Vision, Eyes, Sight
Wasps
Women in Science, Medicine

$ find . -type f | wc -l
70214    ## files

$ find . -type d | wc -l
417      ## subdirectories
```

Answer (score 4):

`find . -type f -name '*.fileextension' | wc -l`

replace the . with the directory path and file extension with the real extension. For example if you are looking for all png files, you replace it with *.png

Answer (score 2):

There are many correct answers here. Here's another!

```
find . -type f | sort | uniq -w 10 -c
```

where `.` is the folder to look in and `10` is the number of characters by which to group the directory.

Answer (score 2):

I have written [ffcnt](https://github.com/the8472/ffcnt) to speed up recursive file counting under specific circumstances: rotational disks and filesystems that support extent mapping.

It can be an order of magnitude faster than `ls` or `find` based approaches, but YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

suppose you want a per directory total files, try:

```
for d in `find YOUR_SUBDIR_HERE -type d`; do 
   printf "$d - files > "
   find $d -type f | wc -l
done
```

for current dir try this:

```
for d in `find . -type d`; do printf "$d - files > "; find $d -type f | wc -l; done;
```

if you have long space names you need change IFS, like this:

```
OIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'
for d in `find . -type d`; do printf "$d - files > "; find $d -type f | wc -l; done
IFS=$OIFS
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(command)) command it displays all the files and folders recursively. As well as it displays count of folders and files in last line of output.

```bash
$ tree path/to/folder/
path/to/folder/
├── a-first.html
├── b-second.html
├── subfolder
│   ├── readme.html
│   ├── code.cpp
│   └── code.h
└── z-last-file.html

1 directories, 6 files
```

For only last line of output in tree command we can use tail command on it's output

```bash
$ tree path/to/folder/ | tail -1
1 directories, 6 files
```

for installing tree we can use below command

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install tree
```

Answer (score 0):

This alternate approach with filtering for format counts all available grub kernel modules:

```
ls -l /boot/grub/*.mod | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the responses given above and comments, I've came up with the following file count listing. Especially it's a combination of [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26458853/2348551) provided by @Greg Bell, with comments from @Arch Stanton
& @Schneems

**Count all files in the current directory & subdirectories**

```
function countit { find . -maxdepth 1000000 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do file_count=$(find "$i" -type f | wc -l) ; echo "$file_count: $i" ; done }; countit | sort -n -r >file-count.txt
```

**Count all files of given name in the current directory & subdirectories**

```
function countit { find . -maxdepth 1000000 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do file_count=$(find "$i" -type f | grep <enter_filename_here> | wc -l) ; echo "$file_count: $i" ; done }; countit | sort -n -r >file-with-name-count.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

find  -type f | wc -l

OR (If directory is current directory)

find . -type f |  wc -l

Comment: This duplicates at least one other answer to this same question.

Comment: It is also wrong since `find -type f` and `find . -type f` are equivalent. By default, `find` searches files in the current directory, so this answer is both repetitive and wrong.

Answer (score -2):

This will work completely fine. Simple short. If you want to count the number of files present in a folder.

```
ls | wc -l
```

Comment: First of all, this does not answer the question. The question is about recursively counting files from a directory forward and the command you show does not do that. furthermore, with ls you are counting directories as well as files.
Also, there is no reason to answer an old question if you are not going to add anything new and are not even going to read the question properly. Please refrain from doing so.

Answer (score -3):

```
ls -l | grep -e -x -e -dr | wc -l
```

1. long list
2. filter files and dirs
3. count the filtered line no