# How to count all files inside a folder, its subfolder and all . The count should not include folder count

Tags: linux, command-line

How to count all files inside a folder, its subfolder and all . The count should not include folder count.

I want to do it in MAC

Comment: Closely, if not the same, related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/9157138/1172302.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

`find . -type f | wc -l` will recursively list all the files (`-type f` restricts to only files) in the current directory (replace `.` with your path).  The output of this is piped into `wc -l` which will count the number of lines.

Answer (score 30):

Find all files under `myfolder` and count them using `wc`. This works on linux:

`find myfolder -type f | wc -l`