# Count files, except the hidden files

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to count all the files from the current folder and each of it's sub-folders.

```
find . -type f \(! -iname ".*" \) -print
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count all files inside a folder, its subfolder and all . The count should not include folder count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9769434/608639)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `find` command:

```
find -type f ! -regex ".*/\.[^/]+$"  | wc -l
```

It will find all files in the current directory with filename not starting with a `.`, aka hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type f -not -path "./.*" | wc -l`

explanation:

find in the current directory(`.`) all things from type file(`f`) which does not have a path that starts with `./.`(`./` is prepend on every output item of find which means current directory) and then give the output to `wc` which is a program to count and the `-l` parameter tells `wc` to count lines.

Comment: This command also list hidden files

Comment: Sorry, corrected it right now. Used `path` instead of `name` and this is working, tried it on my system. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: This new command also matches hidden files nested in subdirectories

Answer (score -1):

Just pip `wc -l` to it like so:

`find . -type f -not -path "*/\.*" | wc -l`

Comment: Please note that the question is about counting non-hidden files, so you must invert the iname condition.

Comment: the files finish .sh doesn't count, do you now how to add it?

Comment: But without adding -iname "*.sh"

Comment: My bad, I just edited my answer.