# Count number of files within a directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, ls

To count the number of files in a directory, I typically use

```
ls directory | wc -l
```

But is there another command that doesn't use `wc` ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `wc` that prevents you from using it?

Comment: Not really.  Unix commands are generally intended to be used this way, chained in pipes.

Comment: I am connecting via ssh to another host to access some data . Unfortunately a bunch of basic commands don't seem to work on this host . If I use wc it returns "unrecognized command" . So I am looking for other options .

Comment: Use the `tree` command. It will give you the tree and at the bottom tell you how many files and directories there are. If you want hidden files also use `tree -a`.

Comment: @vanza "_What exactly is the problem with wc_" , what if a file has a `\n` in the file name?  Yes, _extremely_ unlikely!  But still technically valid and possible.

Comment: @vanza **UPDATE** files with `\n` in the name are displayed on one line by `ls` .  The `\n` is replaced with `?` .  Interesting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307257/is-there-a-bash-command-which-counts-files

Comment: If you want to include subfolders files by counting recursively: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9157162/1176454

Comment: Remember the **-R** for recursively

Comment: Linux requires a professional command/switch to perform this function.

Comment: closed for being off-topic, and it has over 400 upvotes, lol.  I wonder what the highest voted CLOSED question is.

Answer (score 741, accepted):

this is one:

```
ls -l . | egrep -c '^-'
```

Note:

```
ls -1 | wc -l
```

Which means:
`ls`: list files in dir

`-1`: (that's a ONE) only one entry per line. Change it to -1a if you want hidden files too

`|`: pipe output onto...

`wc`: "wordcount"

`-l`: count `l`ines.

Comment: thanks Sajad Lfc , but the egrep command returns a 0 while the wc command returns the correct number of files . Also the wc command works without the -1 included .

Comment: No wait . I made a booboo . You are absolutely right Sajad Lfc .    ls -1 dir | egrep -c ''             This returns the number of files in dir . Thanks .

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath  `ls -l . | egrep -c '^-'` does not count hidden files.  I suggest adding `-a` flag to `ls`.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979: please check my description

Comment: This shows error when there are no files in the folder. Use `ls -1 /dir 2>/dev/null | wc -l`. Here the output from ls is directed to /dev/null and the result is a clean zero

Comment: ls -l | wc -l shows an extra file on Mac. I have 33 files counted manually and also using egrep. wc -l shows 34 instead!

Comment: @runios that's because `ls -l` returns an additional line at the top adding up the file sizes for a total amount. You should use `ls -1` and not the `ls -l`. Also if one wants hidden files but without the directories `.` and `..` you should use `ls -1A | wc -l`

Comment: A weird favourite of mine:  `find . -type f -printf "." | wc -c`

Comment: An effective native way without using pipe: du --inodes [root@cs-1-server-01 million]# du --inodes
1000001 ./vdb.1_1.dir
1000003 .
[root@cs-1-server-01 million]#

Comment: Why is there a hyphen `-` at the end of the patter in `egrep -c '^-'`?

Comment: Isn't this one against the tradition of not parsing `ls`?

Comment: Only @LukeH 's `find` approach is correct. File names with newline characters will over-count in `ls ... | wc ...` approaches. See `f=$(printf '\012f\012f') ; touch "${f}" ; ls -1 "${f}" | wc -l ; find "${f}" -printf '.' | wc -c` prints `3` then `1`.

Comment: TO count recursively within subfolder: 
`find <directory> -maxdepth <maxdepth_value> | wc -l`