# Bash: How to truncate long output of 'ls' with ellipsis in Bash?

Tags: bash

I am customizing my Bash prompt by adding more information, which contains a glance to the list of current directory.

I already understand that changing variable `PS1` would help me with everything. Even more, this variable allows me to execute commands each time.

I've tried to use `ls --color=always` to get a list of files in the current directory. The implementation is below:

```
PS1='... $(ls -F --color=always | xargs | cut -d " " -f -20)\n ...'
```

The shell gets me up to 20 file names in the current directory each time. However, it never tells me if there are more files. What do I need to do? I expect it to tell me with the ellipsis ('...') or something else.

PS: 'ls' seems to behave differently according to the output environment (e.g. tty and file). What if I want a formatted output in the prompt (with more lines)?

Comment: @biffen: `xargs` without any argument is same as `xargs echo`. Basically, OP wants to flatten out all the adjacent white-spaces into a single space character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see the list of files in the current directory before every prompt, you can just set `PROMPT_COMMAND=ls`. Don't play with `PS1` for such purpose.

For your requirement, I think this would work:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="ls | awk 'NR>20{print \"...\"; exit}1' | xargs"
```

Explanation:

1. `PROMPT_COMMAND=something`: Runs `something` before showing the `PS1` prompt.
2. `ls`: list files. Feel free to add `-F` or `--color=auto`
3. `awk 'NR>20{print "..."; exit}1'`: If line number is greater than 20, just print `...` and exit. Else, print line as is (that trailing `1`).
4. `xargs`: To flatten the white-spaces into single space character.

Note: `awk | xargs` can be merged into a single `awk` command, thereby saving you a process for every prompt. However, that would need extra escaping of `"` character, which can get confusing for beginners.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="ls --color=always | awk 'NR>20{printf \"...\"; exit}{printf \$0 \" \";}END{print \"\"}'"
```

Comment: My appreciation to your introduction of `PROMPT_COMMAND`. I am now wondering why there needs to be an `END` in `awk` command. Does the `print ""` sentence only mean a new line before the prompt?

Comment: Earlier `printf` statements do not add the newline `\n`. Explicit `print ""` or `printf "\n"` would add it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just use

```sh
$(ls -F --color=always | xargs | cut -d " " -f -20; [ $(ls -l . | egrep -c '^-') -gt 20 ] && echo ...)
```

The second part is from [Count number of files within a directory in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895290/count-number-of-files-within-a-directory-in-linux#20895338).

Yet I suppose there is a better way (e.g. not calling **ls** twice).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think it possible not to call `ls` twice. Maybe storing the result in a variable shall work, and of course this process needs to be finished in a local function. I'll try it.

Comment: Great. Please let me now what you find.

Comment: I've tried as following: First define a function named `showdir()`. Then define a local variable `local FILES=$(ls --color=always -F)` and show it by `echo ${FILES} | xargs | cut -d " " -f -20; [ $(wc -w <<< "${FILES}") -gt 20 ] && echo " ..."`. In `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND`, just do like this: `... $(showdir) ...`. It seems awkward but OK in this way. I do not know the trade-off exactly.

Comment: Thank You. I'll give it a look!