# Counting files in a huge directory

Tags: linux, bash

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895290/count-number-of-files-within-a-directory-in-linux).

How do I count the number of files in a directory so huge that `ls` returns too many characters for the command line to handle?

```
$ ls 150_sims/combined/ | wc -l
bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

Comment: How many files are in the directory?

Comment: The error message does not match your command. Have you used `ls 150_sims/combined/` or `ls 150_sims/combined/*`?

Comment: Related: [What is the best way to count “find” results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15663607/4518341)

Comment: find 150_sims/ -type f |wc -l

Comment: If you're going to parse `ls`, you'll want to use `ls -f`.  If you have a lot of entries, the performance difference is noticeable.

Comment: If you read the answer to the link in @wjandrea comment, using `find` with `-printf '.'` will output a single `'.'` character per-file which you can pipe to `wc -c` to get the file count. So each file takes no more than a single-character to represent. (at the command line use `getconf ARG_MAX` to get the character limit, usually `2097152` for Linux)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ find 150_sims/combined/ -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

If you're sure there are no directories inside your directory, you can reduce the command to just:

```
$ find 150_sims/combined/ | wc -l
```

Comment: What if a filename contains a permitted line break? [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15663760/3776858).

Comment: Then use `find 150_sims/combined/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '.' | wc -c` and it will work with whatever file name

Answer (score 0):

If there are no newlines in file names, a simple `ls -A | wc -l` tells you how many files there are in the directory. Please note that if you have an alias for `ls`, this may trigger a call to stat (Example: `ls --color` or `ls -F` need to know the file type, which requires a call to stat), so from the command line, call command `ls -A | wc -l` or `\ls -A | wc -l` to avoid an alias.

```
ls -A 150_sims/combined | wc -l
```

If you are interested in counting both the files and directories you can try something like this:

```
\ls -afq 150_sims/combined | wc -l
```

This includes `.` and `..`, so you need subtract `2` from the count:

```
echo $(\ls -afq 150_sims/combined | wc -l) - 2 | bc
```