# How to get the total count of files in a directory using python

Tags: python-3.x, directory, filesystems, counter

I'm currently implementing a docker automation to check whether the number of files in the host mount is equal to docker container mount.

The thing I need to implements

```
cd <source\location\host>
ls | wc -l
```

I'm not getting proper value but when I converted the same into python using below code. Geting some other  value which does not match with `ls | wc -l`

```
 files = folders = 0
        t = Timer(self._seconds, self._stop_loop)
        t.start()
        for _, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            if self._loop_stop:
                break
            # ^ this idiom means "we won't be using this value"
            files += len(filenames)
            folders += len(dirnames)
        t.cancel()
        return folders + files
```

Can anyone help me to identify if this is right approach. If there is an alternative way then kindly share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ls | wc -l` is not a good way to find the number of files in a directory. It won't show hidden files, and it might format in multiple columns. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895338/1904146

Comment: If you do `ls -1a | wc -l` is that (+/- 2) the same number that Python prints ?