# How to count all the files using ls -l statements separated by && in a single line?

Tags: linux, sh

I'm tyring to count all the files from several ls -l statements for certain file types separated by the double amperand symbol like so:

```
ls -l *.xml && ls -l *.json && ls -l *.md
```

The technique I've seen for a single file type or all files will simply count all the end of line characters it finds using an egrep command: `egrep -c '^-'`

Here is a link for a single ls -l command to find the count for all files : [Link to a question about ls -l count using egrep -c command in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895290/count-number-of-files-within-a-directory-in-linux).

If I count several ls -l statements using a command on a single line using like  'ls -l' and for each file type, how do I count each statement's totals in Linux using sh or bash shell script?

I tried this and it doesn't seem to work:

```
ls -l *.xml && ls -l *.json && ls -l *.md | egrep -c '^-'
```

I also tried:

```
ls -l *.xml && ls -l *.json && ls -l *.md | grep -v /$ | wc -l
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't like the '&&' symbols that concatenate the results, and it also doesn't work with the '|' (pipe symbol) for some reason.  The pipe symbol must not work with the '&&' symbol the way I'm using it.

Comment: Why are you using `ls -l` if you only want a **count**?   If you only want count why `-l`?  And if you want more, please be clear in your question what you really want to accomplish here?

Comment: Can't you just do a single ls with all file types of interest?

Comment: I want to count all the files that appear in the ls-l command.

Comment: > I want to count all the files that appear in the ls-l command.
Please explain why you must have `-l`.  What are you really trying to accomplish?  And why must it be one line of code?

Comment: I just updated it to explain why.

Comment: It also works in directories so that is perfect... I guess && creates sub-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use `-d` option for `ls`, to make it not to expand the items that are directories and show all the files inside them.  Second you need to cut the first line (the one that shows `Total 45` at the top).  Third using

```
ls -l *.xml && ls -l *.json && ls -l *.md
```

is equivalente to

```
ls -l *.xml *.json *.md
```

so you can avoid two calls to `ls` and two processes.

There's still an issue with `ls` and it is that you can have no `*.xml` files, and you will get (on stderr, that is) a `*.xml: no such file`.  This is because the `*` wildcard expansion is made at the shell, and it is passed verbatim if the shell is unable to find any file with that name.

So, finally, a way to do so would be:

```
ls -ld *.xml *.json *.md | tail +1 | wc -l
```

#### Note:

I shouldn't use `-l` option, it makes your search more difficult (`ls` takes more time as it has to `stat(2)` each file, it outputs the annoying `Total blocks` line at the top, that you have to eliminate, and you get a blank line between directory listings --this feature is eliminated if you specify option `-d`-- that you should have to eliminate also).  It will skip unreadable files (as the unreadable files cannot be `stat(2)`ed for info, and you are not using the extra information for anything.  You can use just

```
ls -d *.xml *.json *.md | wc -l
```

to get only the names (and also strip the used blocks line at the top) that match the patterns you put in the command line.  If the output of `ls` is piped to another command, then it doesn't group the output in columns, as it  does when outputting to a terminal.

Anyway, if I had to use some tool to count files, I should use `find(1)`, instead (it allows far more flexibility on files selection, and allows you to search recursively a directory structure) as in:

```
find . \( -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.json" -o -name "*.md" \) -print | wc -l
```

or, if you want it to be only in the current directory, just add the option `-depth 1` and you will not get it searching recursively into directories.

```
find . -depth 1 \( -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.json" -o -name "*.md" \) -print | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure if I understood the objective correctly.

If you're wanting a total number of all three types combined:

```
ls *.xml *.json *.md | wc -l
```

Comment: Agreed, the objective is not entirely clear.    This is the simplest answer if the OP really does want only the count.

Comment: @tink - good response! I suspect the OP is just confused about shell arguments; he/she doesn't realize that "ls" will accept multiple  arguments *WITHOUT* needing "&&".

Comment: Will this also work if they are in separate directories?

Comment: I need to re-ask this question using the same file type in specific directories, including the current directory.  But this is excellent info nonetheless!

Comment: @RetroCoder - no, that won't work for 'specific directories', you have you explicitly include which directories you want to look in, e.g. `ls dir1/*.xml dir2/*.json dir3/*.md` ... If you're after all file types in varied directories it becomes more complex and can be approached in quite a few different ways ...

Comment: Yep, that is what I meant.  I didn't have to use the && symbols and I was able to get the count with the wc -l.  I actually wrapped in $paranethesis prepended echo and added 'number of files' without the quotes.