# Recursively count files in all nested Subdirectories in a Linux

Tags: linux, recursion, tree, find

How can I cound recursively number of files in a subdirectry in a Linux system. I know

```
tree
ncdu
```

These commands with really nice and informative output but does not cound files. I was trying to

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 {HERE I SHOULD DO SOMETHING}
```

But fail. Output like this:

```
00. Introduction: 6
04. Topic 1: 18
01. Topic 2: 14
02. Topic 3: 10
05. Details 4: 4
03. Conclusion: 6
```

There is a **spaces and special characters** in directory names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively counting files in a Linux directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9157138/608639)

Answer (score 2):

After researching and testing i've got

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -z | \
while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do \
echo -n "$i: " ; (find "$i" -type f | wc -l) ; done
```

## Explanation

`-maxdepth 1` - I need only one level of recursion

`-type d` - only directories

`-print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i` - I have spaces in directories. The `-r` option to `read` prevents backslash interpretation (usually used as a backslash newline pair, to continue over multiple lines or to escape the delimiters). Without this option, any unescaped backslashes in the input will be discarded. You should almost always use the `-r` option with `read`.

The most common exception to this rule is when `-e` is used, which uses `Readline` to obtain the line from an interactive shell. In that case, tab completion will add backslashes to escape spaces and such, and you do not want them to be literally included in the variable. This would never be used when reading anything line-by-line, though, and `-r` should always be used when doing so.

By default, `read` modifies each line read, by removing all leading and trailing whitespace characters (spaces and tabs, if present in `IFS`). If that is not desired, the `IFS` variable may be cleared, as in the example above.

The IFS variable is used in shells (Bourne, POSIX, ksh, bash) as the input field separator (or internal field separator). Essentially, it is a string of special characters which are to be treated as delimiters between words/fields when splitting a line of input.

The default value of `IFS` is space, tab, newline. (A three-character string.) If `IFS` is unset, it acts as though it were set to this default value. (This is presumably for simplicity in shells that do not support the $'...' syntax for special characters.) If `IFS` is set to an empty string (which is very different from unsetting it!) then no splitting will be performed.

In the read command, if multiple variable-name arguments are specified, `IFS` is used to split the line of input so that each variable gets a single field of the input. (The last variable gets all the remaining fields, if there are more fields than variables.)

`sort -z` - sort output of find in alfabetical order

`do echo -n "$i: "` - print directory name and colon

`find "$i" -type f` - find files only inside each directory

`wc -l` - display number of files (lines of second `find` output)

## Example

```
~/tmp$ tree
.
├── 1000
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_56c7fa8bb58cca0055b0efc2c5ad303d.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_c00f5791305b20d52e16e0f7a4c2e3d9.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10000
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10001
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10005
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10006
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10009
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 1001
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_56c7fa8bb58cca0055b0efc2c5ad303d.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_c00f5791305b20d52e16e0f7a4c2e3d9.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10011
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10015
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10016
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_d4dcbfaafb98dafcbc594b020ce7c54b.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10017
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10018
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10019
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_d4dcbfaafb98dafcbc594b020ce7c54b.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 1002
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_56c7fa8bb58cca0055b0efc2c5ad303d.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_c00f5791305b20d52e16e0f7a4c2e3d9.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10021
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10025
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_6450e078c12f532b29ba57eeb58ca8b3.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10028
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
├── 10029
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
│   ├── 138x116_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_6c8e104b1fc8e31695beb9e950830d64.jpg
│   ├── 640x320_cropped_8ae863ac89a31bf9834085414215be36.jpg
│   └── original_thumb.jpg
└── 1003
    ├── 138x116_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
    ├── 138x116_cropped_56c7fa8bb58cca0055b0efc2c5ad303d.jpg
    ├── 138x116_cropped_c00f5791305b20d52e16e0f7a4c2e3d9.jpg
    ├── 640x320_cropped_50198398faa3c0d168c176824edd4ff7.jpg
    └── original_thumb.jpg

19 directories, 89 files
```

Using explained above one-liner:

```
~/tmp$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -z | \
> while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do \
> echo -n "$i: " ; (find "$i" -type f | wc -l) ; done
.: 89
./1000: 5
./10000: 5
./10001: 4
./10005: 4
./10006: 5
./10009: 5
./1001: 4
./10011: 5
./10015: 4
./10016: 5
./10017: 4
./10018: 4
./10019: 5
./1002: 5
./10021: 5
./10025: 6
./10028: 4
./10029: 5
./1003: 5
```

Comment: Great work @ara-saahov, there my little hack to order by number of files 

      find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -z | \ 
      while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do \
      l=$(find "$i" -type f | wc -l  ) ; echo  "$l : $i" ; done | sort -n