# How can i count the number of files with a specific octal code without them showing in shell

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, tree

I tried using tree command but I didn't know how .(I wanted to use tree because I don't want the files to show up , just the number)
Let's say c is the code for permission
For example I want to know how many files are there with the permission 751

Comment: Please provide examples of what you've tried and how it has not met your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find` with the `-perm` flag, which only matches files with the specified permission bits.

For example, if you have the octal in `$c`, then run

```
find . -perm $c
```

The usual `find` options apply—if you only want to find files at the current level without recursing into directories, run

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -perm $c
```

To find the number of matching files, make `find` print a dot for every file and use `wc` to count the number of dots. (`wc -l` will not work with more exotic filenames with newlines as @BenjaminW. has pointed out in the comments. Source of idea of using `wc -c` is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50009079/12372506).)

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -perm $c -printf '.' | wc -c
```

This will show the number of files without showing the files themselves.

Comment: To make this more robust for exotic filenames (containing a newline, for example), check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/50009079/3266847

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Okay this worked ,  and I definitely  needed -maxdepth 1 too . Thanks a lot .

Comment: If it works, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `zsh` as your shell, you can do it natively without any external programs:

```sh
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB # Just in case it's not already set
c=0751
files=( **/*(#qf$c) )
echo "${#files[@]} files found"
```

will count all files in the current working directory and subdirectories with those permissions (And gives you all the names in an array in case you want to do something with them later). Read more about `zsh` glob qualifiers in [the documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).