# renaming mass files from o to xxxx

Tags: bash, file, rename, directory

I would like to rename multiple folders of files from

**Blackmagic Cinema Camera_1_2013-12-06_2248_C0001_000000.dng**

…

**Blackmagic Cinema Camera_1_2013-12-06_2248_C0001_000322.dng**

to

**0.dng**

…

**322.dng**

So in fact from 0 to xxxx (for safety get to 5 digits if necessary)

I am really new to the terminal tool (on mac osx 10.8) and cannot do the dumbest thing with it, I just know it's the most reliable way to do it, and as they are quite precious files for a project I'm not that keen on using a regular rename application that may do I don't know what slightly more than just rename those files, I just want them to be as pure as they are with the names changed.

So I read many stuff on here but as I know absolutely nothing about any command I can't interpret what was listed on the numerous topics on how to rename as they don't exactly apply to what I want to do. So if you could guys explain to me things as dumb as I am for it to be simple and comprehensible (what has to be explained, actually I just want something to work, not a class), would be great. This forum seems to have good answers quickly, seems all nice

Ah, btw, I would actually run that for a single file first (as a try) and after use it for all the folders of these like-named files. So it's like

**Blackmagic Cinema Camera_1_2013-12-06_2321_C0005**

…

**Blackmagic Cinema Camera_1_2013-12-06_2327_C0000**

for the folders names, each one containing a pile of files named like stated in the first part of this message. so i guess it would need something to apply to all folders of a chosen folder, as there are numerous ones.

(ah, when I say i'm the dumbest guy about it : I can understand, but just have no clue on this stuff, so if you could even tell me how to get to that file/folder/directory etc. whatever be needed to complete it for someone knowing 0)

Thanks in advance, very much !

Comment: So you have a bunch of directories with files that duplicate the directory name and you want to strip the directory name from all the files inside that directory? Do the files always have the number you want at the end? Do you always just want to keep the entire final (`_` delimited) part of the filename?

Comment: It makes more sense to keep a fixed number of digits, if your requirement is not entirely based on aesthetics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script to pad file names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754/bash-script-to-pad-file-names)

Comment: the not fixed number of digits is not aesthetical, the files (photos) are used for movie sequence and the editor needs them in that format (I mean, I guess, have to check).
And Etan : I don't want even the _ that is the added chacacter to the filename from the folder name.
And yeah the files have already the fine number, so yes either just drop the whole folder name + "_" part of it (plus all unneeded 0s), or recreating an increment from 0.

Comment: Tangentially: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers

Comment: Actually, OP seems to un-pad the filenames. `rename 's/Blackmagic Cinema Camera.*0*([0-9]+.dng)/$1/' *.dng` should do it...

Comment: You want `[1-9][0-9]*\.dng` if only to disambiguate.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. How do I go to the actual folder I want to make changes in ?

Comment: @k'dean you can move around the terminal using `cd destination_dir_name`. Check out [this link](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/utilities-how-to/how-to-use-terminal-the-basics/) for more info on terminal basics, fi you haven't already :)

Answer (score 0):

From the directory containing your DNG files:

```
awk -F"[_.]" '$(NF) ~ /dng/ {system("mv "$0" "($(NF-1)+0)".dng");}' <(find .)
```

It worked for me in linux, and it should work in mac os too.

If you have any problem, just leave me a comment ;-)