# Using regex with `rename` version from `util-linux`

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I’m using a GNU/Linux distribution where the utility `rename` comes from `util-linux` and I want to make full use of regular (Perl or POSIX) expressions with it.

There are [two versions of `rename`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086509/4352108) :

- The “Perl” version, with syntax `rename 's/^fgh/jkl/' fgh*`
- The `util-linux` version, with syntax `rename fgh jkl fgh*`

If the use of regexes seems pretty obvious with the first one, to which I have no easy access. However, I’m confused about the second one: I could not find any relevant documentation or examples on the possible use, and in that case the format, of the regular expressions to use.

Let’s take, to make a simple example, a directory containing:

```
foo_a1.ext
foo_a32.ext
foo_c18.ext
foo_h12.ext
```

I want to use a syntax like one of these two lines:

```
rename "foo_[a-z]([0-9]{1,2}).ext" "foo_\1.ext" *
rename "foo_[:alpha:]([:digit:]{1,2}).ext" "foo_\1.ext" *
```

for which the expected output would be:

```
foo_1.ext
foo_32.ext
foo_18.ext
foo_12.ext
```

Of course this does not work! Either I’m missing something obvious, or there is
no implemented way to use actual regular expressions with this tool.

(Please note that I am aware of the other possibilities for renaming files with regular expressions in a shell interpreter; this question aims at a specific version of the `rename` tool.)

Comment: It seems there is no regex support for `util-linux` so are you looking for a solution with the `perl` version even if you have "no easy access to it"?

Comment: @Alepac: given the extensive use I could make of such a tool, I’m considering going through the trouble of installing the “Perl” version. Figuring out how it works should not be too hard once installed!

Comment: Can't you use a bash loop with bash builtin regexp to do that?

Comment: @Alepac: the whole point of this is avoiding the use of a bash loops. The “Perl” version worked perfectly fine once installed! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the manual page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename. It is pretty straightforward:

> rename *from* *to* file...
>
> rename will rename the specified files by replacing the first
>   occurrence of *from* in their name by *to*.

I believe there are no regexes, it is just plain substring match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Seeing you were not mentioning regular expressions, I edited my question to add an example… and in the mean time you added the last precision! I suspect the lack of regex support as well but I’d like someone to give some stronger evidence!

Comment: The man page uses the term `expression` to identify the string to match. Yet nowhere is their any indication that this is an expression other than just a string literal. It seems like a case of unfortunate naming.

Answer (score -5):

The following command gives the expected result with your input file but using the `perl` version:

```
rename 's/foo_\D+(\d+)/foo_$1/' *.ext
```

You can test the command using `-n` option to rename

Comment: This works indeed fine, but it concerns the **other version** of `rename`.