# How can i find and rename multiple files

Tags: linux, centos

I have multiple files in multiple directories and i have to rename these files from lowercase to uppercase; the file extension may vary and needs to be in lowercase (should be renamed too for files with extensions in uppercase).

NB: I have `rename` version from `util-linux` on CentOS Linux7.

i tried this :

```
find /mydir -depth | xargs -n 1 rename -v 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\U$2/' {} \;
find /mydir -depth | xargs -n 1 rename -v 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$2\/\L$2/' {} \;
```

but it's not working it changes nothing and i have no output.

Itried another solution :

```
for SRC in `find my_root_dir -depth`
do
   DST=`dirname "${SRC}"`/`basename "${SRC}" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
   if [ "${SRC}" != "${DST}" ]
   then
      [ ! -e "${DST}" ] && mv -T "${SRC}" "${DST}" || echo "${SRC} was not renamed"
   fi
done
```

this one partially works but transforms the files extensions to uppercase too.

Any suggestions on how to keep/transform the extensions to lowercase ?

Thank you!

Comment: The trailing `{} \;` seems to indicate that you might have confused the syntax of `find`'s `-exec` action with `xargs`. There are two versions of the `rename` command with different syntax. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/31408764/10622916 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086509/10622916. Maybe you have the util-linux version instead of the Perl version.

Comment: yes i have the util-linux version 2.23.2

Comment: The util-linux version cannot use the substitution command, it has a simpler syntax, see https://linux.die.net/man/1/rename. The Perl version might be available with a different name. What Linux distribution and version do you use? Please [edit] your question and add all information to the question.

Comment: @Bodo i edited the question adding the rename version and the distribution ihave

Comment: Don't use `for x in $(find ...)`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution with Perl `rename`:

```
find /mydir -depth -type f -exec rename -v 's/(.*\/)?([^.]*)/$1\U$2/' {} +
```

---

The commands in the question have several problems.

You seem to confuse the syntax of `find`'s `-exec` action and `xargs`.

```
find /mydir -depth -type f -exec rename -v 'substitution_command' {} \;
```

```
find /mydir -depth -type f| xargs -n 1 rename -v 'substitution_command'
```

The `xargs` version has problems in case a file name contains a space.

If you replace `\;` with `+`, multiple file names are passed to one invocation of `rename`.

---

The substitution command is only supported by the Perl version of the `rename` command. You might have to install this version. See [Get the Perl rename utility instead of the built-in rename](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22577767/10622916)

---

The substitution did not work in my test. I successfully used

```
rename -v 's/(.*\/)?([^.]*)/$1\U$2/' file ...
```

The first group `(.*\/)?` optionally matches a sequence of characters with a trailing `/`. This is used to copy the directory unchanged.

The second group `([^.]*)` matches a sequence of characters except `.`.

This is the file name part before the *first* dot (if any) which will be converted to uppercase. In case the file name has more than one extension, all will remain unchanged, e.g.
`Path/To/Foo.Bar.Baz` -> `Path/To/FOO.Bar.Baz`

Answer (score 1):

## `rename`-independent solution (using `find` together with `mv`)

You can rename all files in a directory with a following command:

```sh
for i in $( ls | grep [A-Z] ); do mv -i $i `echo $i | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'`; done
```

First part (`for i in $( ls | grep [A-Z] );`) looks for all uppercase characters and executes until all files are "scanned".

Second part (``) turns all uppercase characters into lowercase ones.

---

## Perl-based `rename` dependent solution

```sh
rename -f 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

This command changes uppercase characters to the lowercase ones. `-f` option allows overwriting of existing files, but **it is not** necessary.

Comment: i tried to use the first suggestion using mv but i get an error
`mv: file1.ext and FILE1.EXT are the same file`
and the issue here is that it transforms even the file extension.

Comment: @TenEM Do you use a case-insensitive file system? Or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

suggesting a trick with `awk` that will generate all required `mv` commands:

```
awk '{f=$0;split($NF,a,".");$NF=tolower(a[1])"."toupper(a[2]);print "mv "f" "$0}' FS=/ OFS=/ <<< $(find . -type f)
```

Inspect the result, and run all `mv` commands together:

```
bash <<< $(awk '{f=$0;split($NF,a,".");$NF=tolower(a[1])"."toupper(a[2]);print "mv "f" "$0}' FS=/ OFS=/ <<< $(find . -type f))
```

#### `awk` script `script.awk` explanation

```
BEGIN { # preprocessing configuration
  FS="/"; # set awk field separtor to /
  OFS="/"; # set awk output field separtor to /
}
{ # for each line in input list
  filePath = $0; # save the whole filePath in variable
  # fileName is contained in last field $NF
  # split fileName by "." to head: splitedFileNameArr[1] and tail: splitedFileNameArr[2]
  split($NF,splitedFileNameArr,"."); 
  # recreate fileName from lowercase(head) "." uppercase(tail)
  $NF = tolower(splitedFileNameArr[1]) "." toupper(splitedFileNameArr[2]);
  # generate a "mv" command from original filePath and regenerated fileName
  print "mv "filePath" "$0; 
}
```

#### Testing:

```
mkdir {a1,B2}/{A1,b2} -p; touch {a1,B2}/{A1,b2}/{A,b}{b,C}.{c,D}{d,C}
find . -type f

./a1/A1/Ab.cC
./a1/A1/Ab.cd
./a1/A1/Ab.DC
./a1/A1/Ab.Dd
./B2/b2/AC.DC
./B2/b2/AC.Dd
.....
./B2/b2/bC.cd
./B2/b2/bC.DC
./B2/b2/bC.Dd

awk -f script.awk <<< $(find . -type f)

.....
mv ./a1/b2/Ab.cd ./a1/b2/ab.CD
mv ./a1/b2/Ab.DC ./a1/b2/ab.DC
mv ./a1/b2/Ab.Dd ./a1/b2/ab.DD
mv ./B2/A1/bC.Dd ./B2/A1/bc.DD
.....
mv ./B2/b2/bC.DC ./B2/b2/bc.DC
mv ./B2/b2/bC.Dd ./B2/b2/bc.DD

bash <<< $(awk -f script.awk <<< $(find . -type f))
find . -type f
```