# Sequelize reading migration files in alphabetic order, but I need different sorting

Tags: sequelize.js, database-migration

A project in question contains migration files with following names:

```
1-addCityToCompany.js
2-addPhonesToCompanies.js
3-addEmailsToCompanies.js
4-addSocialUrlsToCompanies.js
5-addWebstiesToCompanies.js
…
79…
```

Starting from migration 79, we have created a big fork and development was in separate branch.

It's time to merge and deploy ;)

Now we have 239 migrations and want to apply them all to production database.

The problem is that **Sequelize reads migration files, sorted by alphabetical order** and it tries to execute migration 100, skipping migration from 80 to 99.

This is a sequence of reading, I suppose Sequelize using `ls` for that:

```
$ ls -1 migrations/
1-addCityToCompany.js
10-addConfirmedAtToUsers.js
100-createPgcryptoExtension.js
101-createRegisterUserFunction.js
102-setupPostgraphileRoles.js
103-createJwtTokenType.js
104-createAuthenticateFunction.js
105-createCurrentUserFunction.js
106-grantPrivileges.js
107-addAvatarFileIdToUsers.js
108-copy_attachments_to_users_avatarFileId_column_where_attachment_name_is_avatar.js
109-createArticleAttachmentTable.js
11-addHeadCompanyIdToCompanies.js
110-copy_attachment_to_articleAttachment.js
111-drop_attachments_table.js
112-grant_privilegies_for_articleAttachments_table.js
113-create_current_user_id_function.js
114-create_createArticle_function.js
115-set_default_values_for_article_timestamps.js
116-add_primary_key_to_articleAttachments.js
117-create_updateArticle_function.js
118-grant_privilegies_on_DELETE_for_articleAttachment_table.js
119-add_country_id_to_jwtToken_type.js
12-addDepartmentsToCompanies.js
120-create_currentCountry_function.js
121-rename_table_articlesComments_to_articleComments.js
122-set_default_values_for_articleComment_timestamps.js
123-create_createArticleComment_function.js
124-enable_rls_for_articleComment_table.js
125-create_policies_for_articleComment.js
126-create_updateArticleComment_function.js
127-create_country_latest_companies_function.js
128-rename_companiesComments_table.js
129-create_country_latest_company_comments_function.js
13-addDepartmentToCompanyCategory.js
130-rename_companiesInfoRequests_table.js
131-create_country_latest_company_info_request_function.js
132-create_country_regions_with_companies_function.js
133-create_region_cities_with_companies_function.js
134-create_country_cities_function.js
135-create_type_department_as_enum.js
136-change_companies_departments_column_type_from_string_to_enum.js
137-change_companyCategories_department_column_type_from_string_to_enum.js
138-create_type_stock_temperature_as_enum.js
139-change_companies_stockTemperatures_column_type_from_string_to_enum.js
14-addDepartmentToPrimaryKeyOfCompanyCategories.js
…
```

How to control input order of files with Sequelize?

Comment: I know, I can rename migration files with padding zeros, like 080, 081… But maybe Is it possible to overcome this monkey job…

Comment: I also cannot execute `sequelize db:migrate --to 80-…`, because cli starts reading file list from the beginning and tries to execute migration 100.

Comment: I don't see any way to customize the order of the files in the sequelize-cli docs. I believe mass renaming may be the best option. There are programmatic ways to pad zeros in your file names.

Comment: Suddenly, yes, already done it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754/how-to-zero-pad-numbers-in-file-names-in-bash/54888706#54888706